# Resetting the high score in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've recently added a high score for the game I'm currently developing so I've been testing if it works. After testing it, I've reached stage 8 so now the record is set to 8. This is probably a basic question but I'm just wondering how exactly can I reset the record from 8 back to 0?

Comment: I would change it to zero using whatever means you used to change it to 8.

Comment: I used NSUserDefaults to store it? So I just set it to 0? Thanks

Comment: Yes.  [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

Comment: @danh You should post that as an answer so that user1597438 can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to zero the same way as any other change, save `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` in NSUserDefaults.